# JavaScript split() adding extra commas?

Tags: javascript

This is kind of confusing me. I don't know why this is happening, but it is breaking up my program I'm trying to create.

Basically, I have an `var array = []`. This `array` is called `words`. `words` has the contents of

```
var words = ["apple","banana","grape","orange","kiwi","cherry", "strawberry","plum"]
```

When I try to split it with:

```
var split = words.toString().split(" ");
```

it splits each word correctly (`"apple,banana,etc"`).

However doing:

```
var split = words.toString().split("");
alert(split)
```

gives me `"a,p,p,l,e,,,b,a,n,a,n,a,,,g,r,a,p,e,,, etc"`. Why is it doing this?

## EDIT

I don't know why it adds `"a,p,p,l,e,,,..."` with extra commas per word.

Comment: What's really confusing you here ? There's no empty chars, but some commas.

Comment: Updated question; I don't know why it adds extra commas.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Make it in jsfiddle, I don't see this problem on my browser

Comment: In fact `words.toString().split(" ");` does not work correctly, as it gives you `["apple,banana,…"]` (an array of length 1). **Do not use `alert` for debugging!** Try `console.log` instead.

Comment: You don't have extra comma !
You transformed your array to a string so you have : apple,banana,grape,orange,kiwi,cherry
And then you split for each chars so 
a,p,p,l,e,,,b,a,n,a,n,a,,,g,r,a,p,e,,,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
words.toString()
```

gives

```
"apple,banana,grape,orange,kiwi,cherry,strawberry,plum"
```

because `toString()` on an array builds a readable representation with commas separating elements.

If you split that in characters with `.split("")`, you get

```
["a", "p", "p", "l", "e", ",", "b", ...
```

Notice that some of those elements are `","` because you've split a string containing commas.

If you `alert` it, you're implicitly doing an extra `toString()` on that array, which gives

```
"a,p,p,l,e,,,b,a ...
```

If the purpose is to debug, don't use `alert` but `console.log` (you get access to the console with F12 on most browsers).

If your goal is to get an array with all the letters of your words, you may use

```
var letters = [].concat.apply([], words.map(function(v){ return v.split('') }));
```

Comment: Thanks. It won't let me accept the answer for another 10 minutes, so I'll accept it then. I have to do it this way because `words.split("")` gives me `words.split is not a function`

Comment: You get that message because `split` is a function of `String` not `Array` - incidentally, the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for split states that "If separator is an empty string, str is converted to an array of characters.", which is why you get an array of characters

Answer (score 1):

When you use `.toString()` on a array it returns a string with all the values separated by commas.

When you use `.split(" ")`. It doesn't split anything because there are no spaces in your string. It returns a array with one single value.

When you use `.split("")` it splits every character. This creates a array with all characters including the commas `.toString()` added. So when you do:

`var split = words.toString().split("");`

It gives you this array: `["a","p","p","l","e",",""b", etc`

Calling `.toString()` on this array returns your result.

Answer (score 0):

The first `split(words.toString().split(" "))` is trying to split the result of converting `words.toString()` which is `apple,banana,grape,orange,kiwi,cherry,strawberry,plum` with empty spaces, because it doesn't find any empty spaces it return an array with the entire string.

The second split, `var split = words.toString().split("");` you are not passing anything to split method because in javascript `" "` and `""` are not the same. so when you pass `""` to split method javascript assumes that you want to split every single character on the string. basically is the default behaviour of the method when you don't pass anything into it.